# Не работает get_cart_subtotal() в сайдбаре

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

На сайте есть сайдбар для вывода кнопки "Корзина". Я добавил в код вывод

```
WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal();
```

чтобы рядом со словом корзина была сумма товаров в корзине, но все время выводит "0 грн", хотя в корзине товаров на большую сумму.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Корзина инициализируется при запуске WooCommerce, но значения в ней вычисляются только при наступлении определённых событий. В вашем случае надо заполнить корзину текущими значениями, а потом проверять их:

```
wc()->cart->calculate_totals();
wc()->cart->get_cart_subtotal();
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!)

Comment: Только сейчас обнаружил, что из-за вызова этих функций в админке ошибки . Call to a member function calculate_totals() on a non-object . Как это исправить?

Comment: Это значит, что cart не инициализирована, т.е. null. Как же функции выводят вам содержимое корзины? Где вы их используете (откуда вызывается сайдбар - из шаблона страницы?)

Comment: Функцию впихнул в этот код в файле sidebar-init.php

Comment: wc()->cart->calculate_totals();

 register_sidebar(array(
  'name'          => __( "Cart Holder", "themeWoo" ),
  'id'            => 'cart-holder',
  'description'   => __( "Widget for cart in Header", "themeWoo" ),
  'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="cart-holder">',
  'after_widget'  => '</div>',
  'before_title'  => '<h3>',
  'after_title'   => ' ('.wc()->cart->get_cart_subtotal().')</h3>'
 ));

Comment: Это неправильно. register_sidebar идет рано, обычно на событии init. Сделайте шорткод из этих двух функций, вставьте текстовый блок в сайдбар, чтобы выводилось как положено, во время генерации страницы.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду вставить шорткод в код сайдбара?

Comment: не в код, а в админке вставить в сайдбар

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь все работает

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77606/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-homie).